# Why result is 3 for function ZUNIONSTORE?

Tags: redis

```
ZUNIONSTORE out 2 zset1 zset2 WEIGHTS 2 3
output: 3
```

From resourse: http://redis.io/commands/zunionstore

Answer (score 2):

Well, sorted sets are still sets, so they have the semantic of sets.

- zset1 contains (one,two)
- zset2 contains (one,two,three)
- so the set union is (one,two,three)
- zunionstore returns the number of items in the resulting set, so the result is 3

Comment: Thank you, it is obviously, but for what param `WEIGHTS 2 3`?

Comment: WEIGHTS is involved to calculate the score of the items in the resulting set. Let's suppose the score of "one" in zset1 is 1 and 4 in zset2, then with WEIGTHS 2 3, it will be 1*2 + 4*3 in out. WEIGHTS and AGGREGATE  are a way to control how the scores are combined.